# How to Create module class for work manager dependency in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager, dagger-hilt

I have a Worker class that needs an app repository class and the app repository class depends on the API service class. API service class in an interface. I do not know how to create a module class that provides dependency for the Worker class.

I create a module class below

```
@Module
```

@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object ApiModule {

```
@Provides
fun provideLaunchListApi(retrofit: Retrofit): API {
    return retrofit.create(API::class.java)
}
```

I doubt that I am not passing correct input for install In that's why It gives missing binding error, can any one suggest me hoe to create a module class for a worker class dependency.

Comment: Afaik, custom constructor parameters in Worker would also require you to build a custom `WorkerFactory`.

Comment: Ok I will try for it